# Android - Menu Item Crashing on Click (Camera Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a menu item that uses a camera intent. But whenever it is clicked, it crashes. I tested it with several different methods of camera intents, and they all caused crashes. The code is in the link below (as StackOverflow was acting strange when I try to directly insert Java code)

MainActivity/CameraIntent:https://gist.github.com/VirusThePanda/2c99048977c16f7e1ffa

LogCat:https://gist.github.com/VirusThePanda/66a13a58674fdacea224

Menu:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo"
        android:title="Take Photo"
        android:onClick="phototake"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Please note that the MainActivity and Menu is not the full file. Just the important parts for this question.

Comment: Please reformat the question.

Comment: That is the best I could format it. Any other way would not show the code :/

Comment: Nobody is gonna read this question. You will get down votes :/

Comment: I'll repost it then.

Comment: Add more details to your question and then, reformat your code. Otherwise the robot wont let the users edit your post for you and worst, you'll be downvoted.

Comment: I have reformatted the post. Had to use links instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log shows you have SecurityException: Permission Denial...with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA. This means you are targetting API level 23 and the user has revoked the CAMERA permission. You should add code to check and request permission and handle permission acceptance/denial. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: So basically, it's because I didn't add in the runtime permission check? Will this affect below API23 as well?

Comment: I just turned on the permission in settings and it worked. I'll add in the permission request. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can also read about the Permissions pattern in the Material Design Specs: https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/permissions.html